# How to workaround the GCC warning, "the address of XXX will never be NULL"?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm working on a C program. There is a function which takes two pointer arguments, call it `cmp()`. I present here a simplified stand-in for `cmp()` for illustrative reasons:

```
int cmp(struct foo *a, struct foo *b)
{
    return a->bar == b->bar;
}
```

I'd like to make a NULL-check macro, like this:

```
#define SAFE_CMP(a,b) (((a) != NULL && (b) != NULL) ? cmp((a),(b)) : 0)
```

I think this is perfectly fine. However, in when compiling with both `-Wall` and a compliation switch that regards a warning as an error, the following code is troublesome:

```
int baz(struct foo *a)
{
   struct foo b;
   /* ... */
   return SAFE_CMP(a, &b); 
}
```

since gcc warns that *"the address of b will never be NULL"*.

Is there any way to workaround this situation?
Having various helper macro like `SAFE_CMP_1(safe_arg,unsafe_arg)` and `SAFE_CMP_2(unsafe_arg,safe_arg)` etc. is the last thing I want. I'd like to have one helper macro applicable to all situations.

Comment: You could probably use one of the GCC pragmas to disable that warning for the null-check part of the macro, and then re-enable it.

Comment: I don't see what this is buying you. Why can't the `cmp()` function just make these checks?

Answer (score 16):

This seems to suppress the warning for me:

```
#define SAFE_CMP(a,b) (((void *)(a) != NULL && (void *)(b) != NULL) ? cmp((a),(b)) : 0)
```

...but personally, I would just create `safe_cmp()` as a function itself.

```
int safe_cmp(struct foo *a, struct foo *b) {
    return (a && b) ? (a->bar == b->bar) : 0;
}
```

Comment: cmp() in my actual working source is _macro_ also. I think it's better to write into inline function. Very thanks[

Comment: I'd vote this post up more than once if I could! This warning caused me some headache, and the (void*) cast trick may just save the day.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you can typecast to other pointer types, too, to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 2):

> "I'd like to have one helper macro
>   appricable to all situation."

Why?  One size does not fit all.  GCC is doing you a favor by telling you a comparison will *always* have a certain result.  The address of a stack variable will *never* be NULL.  I would just write out the check in baz:

```
int baz(struct foo *a) {
   struct foo b;
   ...
   return a == NULL ? 0 : cmp(a, &b);
}
```

You could also do it in `cmp`.  It depends how you define the pre and post-conditions.

Another possible issue with your macro (not applicable for baz) is that `a` and `b` will be evaluated multiple times.  Beware of:

```
SAFE_CMP(p++, p1++);
```

Comment: I think It's a matter of taste. I'd personally favor all-in-one approach. I'll be happy if gcc checks null whenever I pass two dynamic pointer value. However when I pass static pointer value using that macro, I want gcc not to check and produce such an annoyuing warning.

It's obvious that "return SAFE_CMP(a, &b);" is more clear and readable than "return a == NULL ? 0 : cmp(a, &b);"

Anyway thanks for your kind reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The **gcc** option `-Wno-address` seems to remove the warnings.

Answer (score -1):

When you have such warning consider possibility you have double && && mistake in your if () expression